# One-against-all logistic regression classifier with Vowpal Wabbit

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, vowpalwabbit

I'm attempting a one-against-all logistic regression to classify editorial articles by topic categories based on their text using vowpal wabbit. When I attempt to make predictions for new articles using the same data that was used for training, I have poor results, but I would expect unrealistically good results due to overfitting. In this case, I actually *want* overfitting, because I want to verify that I'm using vowpal wabbit correctly.

My model is being trained on examples that look like this, where each feature is a word from the article, and each label is an identifier of a category, such as sports or entertainment:

`1 | the baseball player ... stadium
4 | musicians played all ... crowd
...
2 | fish are an ... squid`

My training command looks like this:

`vw --oaa=19 --loss_function=logistic --save_resume -d /tmp/train.vw -f /tmp/model.vw`

My testing command looks like this:

`vw -t --probabilities --loss_function=logistic --link=logistic -d /tmp/test.vw -i /tmp/model.vw -p /tmp/predict.vw --raw_predictions=/tmp/predictions_raw.vw`

I'm using `--probabilities` and `--link=logistic` because I want my results to be interpretable as the probability of that article belonging to that class.

I have an obvious issue with the size of my dataset (81 examples and 52000 features), but I expected that this would result in severe overfitting and thus any predictions made on the same dataset as the training data would be quite good. **Am I doing something wrong with my vowpal wabbit commands? Is my understanding of the data science off?**

Here is the output from the training command:

```
Num weight bits = 18
learning rate = 0.5
initial_t = 0
power_t = 0.5
using no cache
Reading datafile = /tmp/train.vw
num sources = 1
average  since         example        example  current  current  current
loss     last          counter         weight    label  predict features
1.000000 1.000000            1            1.0       15        1      451
1.000000 1.000000            2            2.0        8       15      296
1.000000 1.000000            4            4.0        8        7      333
0.875000 0.750000            8            8.0       15       15      429
0.500000 0.125000           16           16.0        8        7      305
0.531250 0.562500           32           32.0       12        8      117
0.500000 0.468750           64           64.0        3       15      117

finished run
number of examples per pass = 81
passes used = 1
weighted example sum = 81.000000
weighted label sum = 0.000000
average loss = 0.518519
total feature number = 52703
```

And for the testing command:

```
only testing
predictions = /tmp/predict.vw
raw predictions = /tmp/predictions_raw.vw
Num weight bits = 18
learning rate = 0.5
initial_t = 0
power_t = 0.5
using no cache
Reading datafile = /tmp/test.vw
num sources = 1
average  since         example        example  current  current  current
loss     last          counter         weight    label  predict features
1.000000 -0.015873            1            1.0 4294967295   3( 7%)      117
1.000000 1.000000            2            2.0 4294967295   3( 7%)       88
1.000000 1.000000            4            4.0 4294967295   3( 7%)      188
1.000000 1.000000            8            8.0 4294967295   9( 7%)     1175
1.000000 1.000000           16           16.0 4294967295   5( 7%)      883
1.000000 1.000000           32           32.0 4294967295   7( 7%)      229
1.000000 1.000000           64           64.0 4294967295  15( 7%)      304

finished run
number of examples per pass = 40
passes used = 2
weighted example sum = 81.000000
weighted label sum = 0.000000
average loss = 1.000000
average multiclass log loss = 999.000000
total feature number = 52703
```

Comment: With `--probabilities` you don't need `--link=logistic` nor `--raw_predictions`. Are your training data shuffled (or natural chronological ordered)?

Comment: @MartinPopel I see, thank you. I'm having trouble finding information about what exactly `--probabilities` and `--link=logistic` do. Yes, I've taken care to shuffle my examples before training. (Thanks to another SO answer of yours actually)

Comment: Have you tried it without `--link=logisitic`? `--probabilities` computes logistic link function internally. Also try omitting `--save_resume`: it is needed only if you need to train the model in more steps (and it may influence the reported test loss if used in the last training step).

Comment: My first rule for multiclass is to use `--ect N` rather than `--oaa N`, the algorithm converges much better.  Also, as you note, you have thousands of features and only 81 examples which may not be enough data to converge so you're not overfitting at all (this is online learning, not batch learning).  Try multiple passes (e.g. with `-c --passes 10 --no_holdout`) to train.  You can see that your error is still very large (about 46% of examples are in error) after one pass.

Comment: Now I see current label=4294967295 in the test output. This is probably the real cause of the high test loss. Do you have gold labels in `/tmp/test.vw`? Is the file properly formated (the same way as`/tmp/train.vw`)?

Comment: @MartinPopel There aren't any labels in test.vw. I've formatted them like this, with no label at all (but still a space): ` | the baseball player ... stadium` When `-t` is used this format should be acceptable, no?

Comment: @MartinPopel can you provide any insight into where that label=4294967295 comes from? Where can I find more info about what vw is doing under the hood to generate this label?

Comment: I've tried omitting `--link=logistic` and `--raw_predictions`, but the results appear the same. However, running multiple passes has yielded much better scores: the error on training has dropped from 46% to 1%. I can't use `--ect` to do multiclass because I need to use `--probabilties`, which is apparently incompatible because an error stating that `--probabilities` is an unrecognized option appears when I do predictions on a set trained with ect. I've posted the new results with multiple passes in my original question.

Comment: 4294967295 = 23^2 − 1 is the highest unsigned int value, a common sentinel value and also a result of assigning -1 to unsigned int. You don't need to have labels in your test set, but then VW cannot compute the test loss, of course. `--ect N` does not support `--probabilities` from obvious reasons: it runs in log N time, but assigning probabilities to all N classes cannot be done in that time. And yes, if you have just 2179 examples and you want to overfit, you need more passes and `--holdout_off`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe my main problem was just that I needed to run more passes. I don't quite understand how vw implements online learning and how this differs from doing batch learning, but after running multiple passes the average loss dropped to 13%. With `--holdout_off` enabled this loss dropped further to %1. Many thanks to @arielf and @MartinPopel

```
Running training command with 2421 examples: vw --oaa=19 --loss_function=logistic --save_resume -c --passes 10 -d /tmp/train.vw -f /tmp/model.vw
final_regressor = /tmp/model.vw
Num weight bits = 18
learning rate = 0.5
initial_t = 0
power_t = 0.5
decay_learning_rate = 1
using cache_file = /tmp/train.vw.cache
ignoring text input in favor of cache input
num sources = 1
average  since         example        example  current  current  current
loss     last          counter         weight    label  predict features
1.000000 1.000000            1            1.0       11        1      234
1.000000 1.000000            2            2.0        6       11      651
1.000000 1.000000            4            4.0        2       12     1157
1.000000 1.000000            8            8.0        4        2       74
1.000000 1.000000           16           16.0       12       15      171
0.906250 0.812500           32           32.0        9        6        6
0.750000 0.593750           64           64.0       15       19      348
0.625000 0.500000          128          128.0       12       12      110
0.566406 0.507812          256          256.0       12        5      176
0.472656 0.378906          512          512.0        5        5      168
0.362305 0.251953         1024         1024.0       16        8      274
0.293457 0.224609         2048         2048.0        3        4      118
0.224670 0.224670         4096         4096.0        8        8      850 h
0.191419 0.158242         8192         8192.0        6        6      249 h
0.164926 0.138462        16384        16384.0        3        4      154 h

finished run
number of examples per pass = 2179
passes used = 10
weighted example sum = 21790.000000
weighted label sum = 0.000000
average loss = 0.132231 h
total feature number = 12925010
```